# Output value from table in view

Tags: php, database, laravel

I've got a problem in Laravel. I have passed my whole table to my view like this from my controller:

```
$usersTable = DB::table('users')->get();
return view('users')->with('users', $usersTable);
```

In a foreach loop I can perfectly get each of the values like this in my view:

```
        @foreach($users as $user => $value) 
            <div class="projectBox">
                <br><span class="projectBoxName">{{ $value->name }}</span>
                @php
                    echo Form::image('/images/edit.png', "",['class' => "editUserBtn", 'userId' => $value->id]);
                @endphp
                <br><span class="projectBoxSmallText projectBoxEmail">{{ $value->email }}</span>
                <br><span class="projectBoxSmallText projectBoxId">ID: {{ $value->id }}</span>
                <br><span class="projectBoxSmallText projectBoxProjects">Currently no projects</span>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

But I also need to access these values outside my foreach loop, how can I do that?

```
   echo Form::text('email', "$users->$value->email", array('placeholder' => "Email"));
```

Ain't working...

This gives my the whole object in this form

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Administrator","email":"admin@mail.com","password":"$2y$10$Re3Ahf.SwU5vj4UvtU5Dy.jxaZMsUNC2WhuJMwsNy9gu6TST4PuRG","remember_token":null}]
```

How to get only the email? I also tried using indexes, but those weren't working.
Thanks!

**Edit:**
Full situation:
I have a list of users with their extra information (mail, tel,...). In those user-boxes there is a button which says 'edit user' when I click that a modal opens giving the current mail and tel. So I can't say in my controller WHO's mailaddress to return because I only know that at the moment the user clicks a client-side button.
**Images:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5ouC.jpg
(Edit button is that small circle with three dots).

Comment: Is there some particular user record whose e-mail you want to use? If so I would grab that specific one out inside your controller, pass it down to your view in a separate variable and use it that way.

Comment: @JeffLambert The problem is, that I only get to know WHICH user I need to get the mail from, at the moment the user triggers a button.

Comment: If you need to lookup the email via a client side action, it would probably be better if you put that logic on the client-side rather than trying to do it solely on the server. You could add a data attribute to something that could be looked up when the button is clicked, and figure out what the e-mail is that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a collection without using loop, you should use collection methods:

```
$users = User::get();
$users->where('name', 'John Smith')->first()->email
```

This will not create any additional queries since you've already eager loaded data.

If you want to load just one user, use `first()` instead of `get()`:

```
$users = User::first();
```

If you'll use `get()` and then `[0]` or `first()` like some guys recommend here, you'll load all users data into the memory for each request which will overload your server.

Also, using indexes to access data (like `$users[4]['email']`) is a bad practice. Avoid it if possible.

Comment: I edited my post. I have imported the whole table into my view because of the reason I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add as first element by adding `[0]`

```
    echo Form::text('email', $users[0]->email, array('placeholder' => "Email"));
```

I suggest use `->first()` instead of `->get()` to get single object. And remove loop and use anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a collection of `users` to get the first user's email, you do

```
$users->first()->email;
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like it's coming in as JSON. Try `json_decode($data)` and `$data->email` to get that attribute.